# How to find out an email is bounced with Spring's MailSender

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am sending emails through Gmail. It sends emails, but when I enter a wrong email address it does not throw an exception; however, the email will be sent to me.

I changed my email configuration and it threw Authentication exception but it does not throw SendMail exception for wrong email addresses.

```
try {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(receiverEmail); //the value is xc@cvcbdfgxcvwesdc.org
        message.setCc(myEmailAddress);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);
        mailSender.send(message);

    } catch (MailSendException send) { //I used MailException as well
        send.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I added following code but it does not show anything

```
} catch (MailSendException send) { // failed to send /there is one other
                                            // type of exception
            System.err.println("failed messages size:" + send.getFailedMessages().size());
```

Comment: The sending/receiving of mail is not synchronous event.  Do you expect the client to know every valid email address?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes I need to make sure the email is not bounced.

Comment: In that all I can suggest is that you get the user to click on a link when they receive a mail, otherwise assume the mail is NOT received.

Comment: I am a bit confused then what the MainSendException and MailException are good for?

Comment: In you case, the mail is successfully sent.  As per the javadocs  `Note that a general mail server connection failure will not result in failed messages being returned here: A message will only be contained here if actually sending it was attempted but failed`

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks, how to call public final Map getFailedMessages() ? I can not find it

Comment: @ScaryWombat I do not get the difference between authentication and mailsendexceptions.

Comment: The mail server can reject a specific address, i.e. one of its own addresses. However if it has to forward the mail elsewhere it can't know the address is invalid at that time.

Comment: See also this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr).

Comment: @EJP I even  removed the cc part but does not show anything.

Answer (score 3):

The MailSender won't be able to determine if email bounced back in the sense you imagine, at least not during the send process. The code there will only tell you if there is exception within the code that prevents it from sending email.

Bounced email response will hit the mail server, in which case you would need to implement a mechanism such as the Mail-Receiving Channel Adapter 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html.

Only when you read the bounced email from your mail server can you then determine the reason for failure and thus determine appropriate response.

Hope this helps a bit.