# How to read a bounce back email details with Java mail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I am using Java mail API to read the bounce back email from Amazon SES on my Gmail id.

This is how I receive an bounce email from Amazon SES.

```
<email content start>

An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 user unknown
Status: 5.1.1



---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: fullstack.rahultokase@gmail.com
To: bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Date: Sun, 17 Dec 2017 15:27:30 +0000
Subject: bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
bounce@simulator.amazonses.com

<email content end>
```

My question is using Java email API. I am able to read the content up to:

```
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
```

But I am not able to read the following content with the help of Java email api

```
Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; bounce@simulator.amazonses.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 user unknown
Status: 5.1.1
```

How can I read the above content in the email?

Comment: Bounce messages are defined in [RFC 6533](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6533), but not all servers follow all the rules. Look at the MIME structure of the bounce message and try to find the "attachment" that is the actual Delivery Status Notfication (DSN). Be prepared to do this for different kinds of mail servers and configurations.

Comment: See also the [com.sun.mail.dsn package](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagnostic code information is a part of message content and can be read using the following code.

```
MimeMessage payload = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();
    Multipart mp = (Multipart) payload.getContent();
    for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                        BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        IOUtils.copy(bodyPart.getInputStream(), writer);
                        System.out.println("Content inputstream: " +  writer.toString());


    }
```

Comment: can you please look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551114/how-to-find-out-an-email-is-bounced-with-springs-mailsender

Answer (score 0):

The information that you are looking for (Action, Final-Recipient, Diagnostic-Code, Status) are set in the headers of the message, you can get it with

Considering that msg is the message object:

```
  ... 
  final String[] diagnostics = msg.getHeader("Diagnostic-Code"); 

  for (String dx_code : diagnostics) {
     System.out.print(dx_code);
  }
  ...
```

the second value (in the example `diagnostics[1]`) will contain the error code that indicates if it is a hard bounce 550 (for instance the email address does not exist), or a soft bounce 450 (for example, the inbox bin is full)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion I have tried your solution but its not working. Instead of header i found that diagnostic code information was in the bodypart content.